# Problemas com navbar

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Sou iniciante em web e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em HTML5, onde utilizo Bootstrap. Há uma navbar no topo da página e na navbar há uma lista. Porém ao realizar a implementação, as opções da lista estão sobrepostas, causando o problema de não exibir todos os itens da lista, pois todos os itens da lista estão um sobre o outro.

Segue trecho do código implementado sem o funcionamento correto

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-togle="collpase" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expander="true">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse-in" id="myNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#sobre">SOBRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#servicos">SERVICOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portifolio">PORTIFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#precos">PRECOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: lista com opções sobrepostas]

Segue código quando isolado e funcionando

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-togle="collpase" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expander="true">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse-in" id="myNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#sobre">SOBRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#servicos">SERVICOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portifolio">PORTIFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#precos">PRECOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Imagem deste código com a navbar funcionando

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desculpem se não fui muito claro. Pesquisei em outros tópicos e não encontrei respostas.

Comment: ou seja, voce conseguiu resolver? ou tem algum problema? nao deu pra entender, seria bom tb ter o seu codigo do `main.js`

Comment: O main.js está vazio, estou usando apenas as classes e plugins do bootstrap por enquanto.
Ainda não consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: mas qual é o problema? os codigos me parecem iguais @Dan exceto pelas referencias aos arquivos do jquery e do bootrap `js`

Comment: O problema é que as opções da lista aparecem sobrepostas na navbar. Da uma olhada no código completo aqui http://pastebin.com/Z2SgJL4i e aqui http://pastebin.com/EVBMSbcX

Comment: agora sim... o problema esta no seu css, que vc nao colocou na pergunta, hehehehe

Comment: Creio que não, pq no código que fiz isolado, sem a css, funcionou perfeitamente. Mas posta aí pra noix, heheheh

Comment: olha o link que coloquei na resposta, está com o seu css ( faz essas alteracoes que te falei e vai ver que vai funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no seu CSS 
você precisa remover o seu `text-indent: -999px;` e o `width: 10px;`

Pode verificar clicando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/o5ftj507/1/)

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid @carousel-indicators-border-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Pega o código completo agora e testa

Comment: mesmo código, apenas adicionei as referencias

Comment: editei com o codigo

Comment: Então, apenas este trecho, sozinho, tambem funciona aqui, o problema é quando coloco no código ja completo. Vou continuar pesquisando, caso descubra, posto aqui, blz?

Comment: Cara, acho que o problema ta em meus navegadores, so pode!! Fiz as alterações, testei e o problema persiste. Vou continuar validando até encontrar o erro e volto a postar. Vlw pela força

Comment: usou o CTRL + F5 ou CTRL + SHIFT + R no chrome? por conta do cache ??

Comment: Funfou. Cara, passei o dia nisso euheuheuheuhe, vlw, hein!!! Onde dou um voto maroto?

Comment: clicka no Vzin da resposta